# Do you know any PHP library to write logs with JSON format?

Tags: php, json, logging

I read this article http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2011/12/26/log-for-machines-in-json/ about how to log a NodeJS application using JSON format.

I think is quite interesting and I was searching for something similar for PHP, but keywords "PHP", "Logs" and "JSON" doesn't work well together at Google ^^u

Do you know or use anything to log at JSON format in your PHP applications?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog). Its a default logging library for symfony2 also.

And check the json formater

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend Monologo, here you have basic usage of monolog:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/usage.md

In your case use JsonFormatter